# Visual Studio code snippets and properties

Tags: visual-studio-2012, properties, user-controls, code-snippets

I've just decided that using a code snippet would be quicker for me that to rewrite the same markup over and over.

I've created my snippet with the expectation that I could just tell it "put the snippet here" and it'll automatically write in the markup based on the markup specified in the snippet.

While this is the case using the `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+X` keyboard shortcut combination, it's quite a bit more involved than I was hoping, so I figured I'd use the shortcut (in this case `<ort>`), but I can't seem to figure on how to get the dynamic parts of the snippet set there.

I was hoping I could specify properties on the snippet so I could write it into the page something like this:

```
<ort fieldtext="Username" fieldinputcontrolname="txtUsername" />
```

I have a feeling I might be looking for a user control here, but I'm not sure how I'd write a user control that would dynamically specify control names based on property values...

Can this be done with snippets or should I just use a user control?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Snippet Designer tool by any chance?
If not give it a shot. Their team knows alot about snippets. and they are fairly prompt with the answers to the questions you might throw at them.
Sorry if it's not a direct answer but they helped me solve one of the issues which I was bugged in for a while.